# Почему pyrogram не видит описание чата?

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

я пишу в свой чат с описанием и

```
@app.on_message()
async def handler(_, msg: types.Message):
    print(msg.chat.bio)
    print(msg.chat.description)
```

вот это /\ выводит вот это \/

```
None
None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`description` возвращает только `await app.get_chat()`